# Probability distribution from product of conditionals

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $p(x,y,z)$ be a joint distribution on a finite set. 
Consider the following quantity:
$$
q(x,y,z):=p(x|y)\,p(y|z)\,p(z|x).
$$
What can we say?

1. Is $q$ a probability distribution (i.e. normalized)?
2. If yes, what is its marginal $q(x,y)$?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I am *not* interested in trivial cases where $p(z|x)=p(z)$, or the same for $x,y$. What can we say in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is generally not a probability distribution. For $x,y,z\in\{0,1\}$, consider

$$
p(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}\frac12&x=y=z\;,\\0&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}
$$

Then $q(x,y,z)=2p(x,y,z)$, which is not a probability distribution.